# Do I have to repackage my docker image for it to be able to run on AWS Graviton(ARM) based EKS/ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, x86, arm, aws-graviton

Suppose I already have a bunch of x86 docker images.

They are currently running on x86 based AWS EKS and ECS.

If I want to switch to AWS Graviton(ARM based), do I have to repackage my docker images?

And if my base images are not ARM, and they are not made/controlled by me but I have to rely on them, is there a way for my images to run on AWS Graviton(ARM based) EKS and ECS?